# Windows 10 v1909 Memory Leak

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, memory-leaks, windows-10-v1909

Windows 10 Pro v1909 Intel i5-8250U 8GB RAM

I updated to v1909 from v1809 back in December, and since then, I've noticed that my Memory used at idle and my paged/non-paged pool is significantly more than it used to be, particularly after my computer has been running for awhile. This problem was present in a somewhat more mild form in 1809, but not at all in 1803.

Prior to the update, my system would take about 21-30 days to grow from 100mb paged/400mb nonpaged to ~500/1000 respectively, in about 2 weeks or less (most recently in just over 9 days), assuming I just do basic web browsing; some YouTube, some Twitch at most. If I do things like run my antivirus, or a decent bit of troubleshooting (eg lots of opening new windows), it seems to grow faster. I don't recall what my paged/non-paged used to be, but I keep seeing that ~300mb is supposed to be normal for non-paged, and mine is usually about 600-750mb, but can sit at 1GB after only 14-16 days uptime. Neither seem to be ticking down at all when left alone; if anything, they seem to very slowly be ticking up, indefinitely.

I've been trying to figure out the source of the change/problem, but I'm not exactly computer savvy; I just have Google and some spare time.

I tried using PoolMon, and from what I could make sense of, the largest non-paged thing listed was IAStor, which I do not know where to update the driver for (if it has one). Also, the Empty Standby List thing in Rammap didn't work, either. I have also tried restarting Windows Explorer after seeing that it had a lot of paged/non-paged memory usage, but it did nothing.

I've also tried to see if it was something to do with my Network Data Usage Monitor (I keep seeing it referred to as NDU), as I've seen that be listed as a culprit (though usually with Killer as the device, whereas I have Intel as best I can see) particularly since the "Network" box has a habit of disappearing from my Task Manager's Performance tab (it also doesn't show usage in Processes either, even though the status column is there) after my computer has been running for awhile. I ran the diagnostic for it in Windows, and it didn't see anything. Network still doesn't show in my Performance tab so I don't think it did anything, and I don't know what else to do to pursue this avenue.

Has anyone else had this issue? Is it some sort of driver issue or is it a Windows issue? And more importantly, does anyone have a clue as to how I can resolve it (preferably without having to trapeze through the messy business of altering the registry)?

Comment: Is there an actual *issue* besides increased memory usage? *Does this affect performance or reliability in any way*, and what have you measured?

Comment: It does seem to slow down responsiveness the closer it gets to that 2 week point. I notice that it can take a few seconds for folders to open and Chrome tabs take longer to load too (particularly YouTube/Twitch). After a restart, everything is snappy again, but it inevitably goes back to slowing down. It's been a thing since I upgraded from 1803 to 1809, and has just gotten worse in 1909.